# How to calculate Beginning and End Intersections of Polylines?

Tags: arcmap, line, network, polyline-creation

I have ArcMap 10.8.2 and am working with road networks consisting of intersecting polylines. Each segment has its own ID and I would like to calculate its position relative to other segments.
The attached images are a very basic illustration.

Is there any tool or process I could employ that would calculate the "Start" and "End" based on the attributes of the intersecting lines?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Uneducated guess: Would the Spatial Join geoprocessing tool work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial Join and a bit of processing will determine connectivity. Be aware from your sample its impossible to determine direction of line, so the approach below lists what is connected but not directionality.

Here is some sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Here is the spatial join tool, note its joining to itself with a 1:M relationship

[image: Spatial join]

Looking at the outputs attribute table select where ID's are the same and delete them out.

[image: Select and delete]

Note only A and E occur twice in the resulting table, these are the polylines that join other polylines

[image: Results]

Note this approach assumes no self intersection, e.g. middle of A polyline touches C for example.